# Force R to use single quotes in dbplyr mutate_at Spark translation

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I wish to use `dplyr::mutate_at()` on a Spark DataFrame to convert a date column. Let's say this is my data:

```r
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local")
df <- dplyr::copy_to( 
  sc, 
  data.frame(x = structure(18601, class = "Date")), 
  "df" 
)
df
# # Source: spark<df> [?? x 1]
#   x         
#   <date>    
# 1 2020-12-04
```

If I want to extract elements of this date, I can use the Hive UDF `date_format(., fmt)` however when specifying the `fmt`, one must use single quotes. However my attempts to do so are thwarted since R converts the single quotes to double quotes.

```r
mutate_at(df, "x", ~date_format(., 'E')) %>% dbplyr::sql_render()
# <SQL> SELECT date_format(`x`, "E") AS `x`
# FROM (SELECT date_format(`x`, "E") AS `x`
# FROM `df`) `q01`
```

Note how the `'E'` has become `"E"`. I have tried to build the call but this doesn't work either

```r
call(name = "date_format", quote(.), quote('E'))                                                                                                             
# date_format(., "E")
```

I am fully aware that there are other ways to do this, however this is the way my use case requires me to do it so please be specific in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use `mutate` and `date_format` as follows:

```
> df %>% mutate(x = date_format(x, 'E'))
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
  x    
  <chr>
1 Sat
```

You could also compose the SQL with single quotes using `sdf_sql`:

```
> sdf_sql(sc, "SELECT date_format(x, 'E') AS x FROM df")
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
  x    
  <chr>
1 Sat
```

I assumed you are using Spark 3.0.1